# I need help changing the data acquisition rate of a LabVIEW Read VI connected to a servo motor

Tags: labview, servo

I have a labVIEW program designed to output position and velocity of a servo motor. I need to change the data acquisition rate, and I am unsure of how to do this.

I can't copy and paste labVIEW code, however I can send an email with a link to the file.

Comment: Hi! Are you able to use links? If so, create a block diagram snippet and upload it to imgur: open the VI's block diagram, Edit :: Select all, Edit :: Create VI snippet from selection

Comment: @JoeFriedrichsen: once one has the snippet, it can be uploaded here, too!

Comment: @JoeFriedrichsen , here is a link to the snippet that I'm having problems with https://imgur.com/a/5mbDeOt

Comment: hrm, I can't seem to drag it into an empty LabVIEW block diagram. Did you use the Edit menu to create this, because it's behaving like a print-screen screenshot. I don't know the names of the blue express VIs in your program and if the snippet isn't created by LabVIEW, I won't be able to view them to check.

Comment: @JoeFriedrichsen this should work now, sorry about that, https://imgur.com/a/dFECHEh

Answer (score 0):

Using [your VI snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gr6Jh.jpg), the blue-tinted block that queries the position and velocity of the servo motor is the [Soft Motion Read Express VI](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371093V-01/nimclvfb/dt/eng/generated/exread_00a10037/), which executes on-demand each time your VI runs the loop that owns it.

To change the query rate, you need to change the loop rate, and the loop's rate is governed by the [Wait Until Next ms Multiple VI](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361N-01/glang/wait_till_next_ms_multiple/). Currently, your VI uses `1` (millisecond), which makes 1 kHz the upper bound on the loop rate. Because this wait VI uses integer milliseconds for its input, you can only slow the loop down. If you change the value to `2`, then your VI will query at a 500 Hz maximum rate. `3` yields 333 Hz, `4` 250 Hz, and so on.

Comment: that seems to have no effect on the number of data points created. The Read Express VI samples at around 70 Hz for every trial.

Comment: If 70 Hz is the current loop rate, then other code is also running and consuming time before the while loop executes again. The input to **Wait Until ms Multiple** won't have an effect on your program until it throttles the loop rate further. If you set the value to 15 ms, then your loop rate ceiling becomes 67 Hz. As you increase the wait time, the acquisition will slow down.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the boolean line from the while loop below is maybe the one slowing down your sample loop. You can insert loop timing into both those loops and see if they clock the same. 
If they do then that is your issue. 
You'd be better of using a queue to pass the boolean. I'd go as far as to say in 99% of cases you want to use a queue to pass data inbetween loops or you might slow down execution.
Instruction how to time your loops.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZZ36utKlrE

If that is not the problem then its the read vi that is slow. 
You can check if there is and sample freq input on that vi you can adjust.